# Open a document in PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I have a method called `Save` which saves a PDF document at a specified location.

```
PdfDocument Document=new PdfDocument();
public void Save(string pathWithFileName)
{
     Document.Save(pathWithFileName);
}
```

Now I draw some paragraphs, using `XGrahics` class. Then I save the document using `Save` method. It works perfectly.

Now I want to reopen document, add some stuff and again save the document. How can I do this?

Comment: what problems have you faced in opening have you tried opening it

Comment: When i tried to add another paragraph in document it crashes.

Comment: I presume "crashes" means "throws an exception". If you disclose details about the exception we can help you understand the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open an existing document, use Open() with the correct pathname:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filenameDest);
```

Then make the changes. Finally save it as you already do:

```
document.Save(filenameDest);
```

PDFsharp comes with several samples.
You can download the complete sample code here:
http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/618773

Sample snippets and explanations can be found here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question more: When I open the document again for adding some text, I must to  updated the `XGraphics`, isn't it ?

Comment: The `XGraphics` object is associated with a `PdfPage` object. After opening the PDF file you have a new `PdfPage` and you will need a fresh `XGraphics` object for that page.